# How to solve lighthouse error when using custom config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lighthouse

I have use the following code to run lighthouse:

```js
import lighthouse from 'lighthouse';
import * as chromeLauncher from 'chrome-launcher';

const launchChromeAndRunLighthouse = async (url) => {
  const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch();
  const options = { port: chrome.port };
  const runnerResult = await lighthouse(url, options, {
    settings: {
      extends: 'lighthouse:default',
      screenEmulation: {
        disabled: true,
      },
      extraHeaders: process.argv[2] === 'true' ? {
        'k8scluster': 'true',
      } : {},
      artifacts: {},
    }
  });
  await chrome.kill();
  return runnerResult.lhr;
};

const NUM_RUNS = process.argv[3] ? parseInt(process.argv[3]) : 10;
const targetURL = process.argv[4] || 'https://www.google.com/';

const runLighthouseMultipleTimes = async (url, numRuns) => {
  const runs = Array.from({ length: numRuns }, async () => {
    const result = await launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(url);
    return result;
  });

  return Promise.all(runs);
};

runLighthouseMultipleTimes(targetURL, NUM_RUNS)
  .then((results) => {
    // Calculate the average scores
    const avgPerformanceScore =
      results.reduce((sum, result) => sum + result.categories.performance.score, 0) / NUM_RUNS;
    const avgAccessibilityScore =
      results.reduce((sum, result) => sum + result.categories.accessibility.score, 0) / NUM_RUNS;
    const avgBestPracticesScore =
      results.reduce((sum, result) => sum + result.categories['best-practices'].score, 0) / NUM_RUNS;
    const avgSEOscore = results.reduce((sum, result) => sum + result.categories.seo.score, 0) / NUM_RUNS;

    console.log(results);

    console.log(`Average Performance Score: ${avgPerformanceScore}`);
    console.log(`Average Accessibility Score: ${avgAccessibilityScore}`);
    console.log(`Average Best Practices Score: ${avgBestPracticesScore}`);
    console.log(`Average SEO Score: ${avgSEOscore}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error running Lighthouse:', err);
  });
```

And I received `Error running Lighthouse: Error: No artifacts were defined on the config` from this code block in `lighthouse/core/gather/navigation-runner.js`:

```js
async function _navigations(args) {
  const {
    driver,
    page,
    resolvedConfig,
    requestor,
    baseArtifacts,
    computedCache,
  } = args;

  if (!resolvedConfig.artifacts || !resolvedConfig.navigations) {
    throw new Error('No artifacts were defined on the config');
  }

  /** @type {Partial<LH.FRArtifacts & LH.FRBaseArtifacts>} */
  const artifacts = {};
  /** @type {Array<LH.IcuMessage>} */
  const LighthouseRunWarnings = [];

  for (const navigation of resolvedConfig.navigations) {
    const navigationContext = {
      driver,
      page,
      navigation,
      requestor,
      resolvedConfig,
      baseArtifacts,
      computedCache,
    };

    let shouldHaltNavigations = false;
    const navigationResult = await _navigation(navigationContext);
    if (navigation.loadFailureMode === 'fatal') {
      if (navigationResult.pageLoadError) {
        artifacts.PageLoadError = navigationResult.pageLoadError;
        shouldHaltNavigations = true;
      }
    }

    LighthouseRunWarnings.push(...navigationResult.warnings);
    Object.assign(artifacts, navigationResult.artifacts);
    if (shouldHaltNavigations) break;
  }

  return {artifacts: {...artifacts, LighthouseRunWarnings}};
}
```

What is wrong with my config and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I received the same issue when trying to run lighthouse scan from cmd on Windows. I used the `--config-path=path/to/the/config-file.js` parameter for having a lighthouse scan with my custom parameter settings. This file contained the settings the same way you defined yours in `line 7` in the first code snippet.

In my case - that may help you - I needed to re-structure the settings this way:

```
const runnerResult = await lighthouse(url, options, {
  extends: 'lighthouse:default',
  settings: {
    screenEmulation: {
      disabled: true,
    },
    extraHeaders: process.argv[2] === 'true' ? {
      'k8scluster': 'true',
    } : {},
  }
});
```

Sources:
[GitHub, lr-desktop-config](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/core/config/lr-desktop-config.js)
[GitHub, constants](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/core/config/constants.js)

Hope it helps!